# how to send csv data from logstash to graphite

Tags: csv, logstash, graphite

how to send csv data output to graphite using logstash.

I tried with the following conf

```
output { graphite { host => "10.206.72.108" port => 2003 type => "aggregate_report" metrics => ["hosts.%{@source_host}.average","%{average}"]
}
}
```

But it does not working.

CSV input has following

```
sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_report_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth
POST 1,3,616,649,730,470,730,0.0,1.6216216216216215,1.2600295608108107
POST 5,15,1384,1412,2212,488,2271,0.0,2.2378039683723707,2.418022946814859
POST 10,30,3153,3064,4942,593,5558,0.0,1.8867924528301887,1.8191086871069182
POST 15,45,4110,3986,6686,557,8387,0.0,2.06280082512033,2.0691575464130185
POST 30,90,7017,6963,12209,559,14058,0.0,2.2537750732476898,2.2543375388150153
POST 60,180,13523,13153,24065,532,27023,0.0,2.2623581312921837,2.2354042551185853
POST 200,600,37985,36469,69359,542,82112,0.07666666666666666,2.574930476877124,2.741672312738181
TOTAL,963,27164,21025,64450,470,82112,0.04776739356178609,2.4136971674774985,2.50476349981703
```

please help me

Comment: can you give the error message?

Comment: Yes, and what do the messages look like? Include `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` in your output section and post a sample message.

Comment: {"message"=>[[0] "TOTAL,963,27164,21025,64450,470,82112,0.04776739356178609,2.4136971674774985,2.50476349981703\r"],"@version"=>1","@timestamp"=>"2015-01-07T06:14:11.244Z","host"=>"logstashtest.amers1.cis.trcloud","path"=>"/home/cloud/sample1.csv","sampler_label"=>"TOTAL",aggregate_report_count"=>"963","average"=>"27164","aggregate_report_median"=>"21025","aggregate_report_90%_line"=>"64450","aggregate_report_min"=>"470","aggregate_report_max"=>"82112","aggregate_report_error%"=>"0.04776739356178609","aggregate_report_rate"=>"2.4136971674774985","aggregate_report_bandwidth"=>"2.5076349981703"}

Comment: This is what i get when add ,stdout { codec => rubydebug }

Comment: Hi,Now i am able to send message to graphite. But it is reading the  csv from end of the file though i have given in conf position to start from beginning.

Comment: Carbon sends all the datapoints to graphite , but in graphite i can see only one datapoint that also it sends when i am starting logstash at the first time. After that i can see null values in raw data. Any help will be appreciated.